# Declare state event to stop video when exit full screen javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to stop a video to play when quitting the fullscreen mode.

I'm using the below code to detect when exiting the full screen mode:

```
 $('video').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
     var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
     var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';
```

How do i declare something like the following code?

```
if FUllscreenOff,  $("video").each(function () {
     this.pause();this.currentTime = 0;
})
```

It will be super usefull, thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can do by

```
$("video").each(function () {
this.addEventListener(
  'fullscreenchange',
  function(event) {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
       this.pause();
       this.currentTime = 0;
    }
  },
 false
);
```

I have not checked please checked once and let me know

Comment: Hi Ankit,

Thanks for this;  unforutnately it doens tseem to work . . . any other advice ?

Thanks for all